# TensorFlow Session Error: kernel version 352.63.0 does not match DSO version 361.93.2

Tags: tensorflow

I've installed TensorFlow with CUDA and CuDNN.

Why I run a session I've the following error:

````
```
>>> sess = tf.Session()
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:491] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:153] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: next-gpu1
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:160] hostname: next-gpu1
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:185] libcuda reported version is: 361.93.2
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:347] driver version file contents: """NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  352.63  Sat Nov  7 21:25:42 PST 2015
GCC version:  gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
"""
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] kernel reported version is: 352.63.0
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:296] kernel version 352.63.0 does not match DSO version 361.93.2 -- cannot find working devices in this configuration
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:81] No GPU devices available on machine.
```
````

Answer (score 2):

The driver version is lower than cuda dso version,so you get this error.

You can download and install the new driver of cuda

./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.93.2.run (may stop X window first)

PS: If can't resolve ,please reinstall cuda

Reference: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4349

Comment: If you run into this problem on AWS EC2 you can find the pointers to the drivers you need to download on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/accelerated-computing-instances.html#install-nvidia-driver

Answer (score 2):

The following solved it for me on AWS EC2:

```html
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y linux-aws
sudo reboot
```